# Determine workers on duty during timeframe

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data (simplified):

```
PersonID    Started             Finished            HoursWorked
Person1     2020-07-13T07:00:23 2020-07-13T14:30:23 7.30
Person2     2020-07-13T22:00:12 2020-07-14T07:10:28 9.10
```

Note how Person 2 is a night worker, starting on the 13th PM and into the 14th AM, and that workers in the day finish at half past the hour.

I need to produce a table that shows:

```
PersonID   Started             Finished                12-2am  2-4am   4-6am   6-8am   8-10am
Person2    2020-07-13T22:00:12 2020-07-14T07:10:28     2       2       2       1       0
```

with that same table showing also for further example:

```
PersonID    Started             Finished            6-8am   8-10am  10-12pm 12-2pm  2-4pm
Person1     2020-07-13T07:00:23 2020-07-13T14:30:23 2       2       2       1       0.5
```

The idea being that I can then run a query that totals the number of hours in that 24hr period, but being mindful that night workers will work 2hrs of one day, and 7 of the next. So far I've tried doing a substantial case statement to cover the two hours slots, but although I know what's wrong (it only counts the first interval - eg starts at 07:00 so populates the 6-8 timeframe, and also only puts a 1 in there, regardless of 1 or 2hrs in that slot), I can't figure out how to arrive at the above table. My SQL skills are OK, but certainly not as good as most members of this forum. My code at present (ignore my poor formatting) is:

```
select concat(s.firstname, ' ',s.lastname) as "Worker", left(wt.[started],19) as "Started", left(wt.[finished],19) as "Finished", 

COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '00:00:00' and '02:00:00' THEN 1 END) "0000-0200",
COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '02:00:00' and '04:00:00' THEN 1 END) "0200-0400",
COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '04:00:00' and '06:00:00' THEN 1 END) "0400-0600",
COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '06:00:00' and '08:00:00' THEN 1 END) "0600-0800",
COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '08:00:00' and '10:00:00' THEN 1 END) "0800-1000",
COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '10:00:00' and '12:00:00' THEN 1 END) "1000-1200",
COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '12:00:00' and '14:00:00' THEN 1 END) "1200-1400",
COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '14:00:00' and '16:00:00' THEN 1 END) "1400-1600",
COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '16:00:00' and '18:00:00' THEN 1 END) "1600-1800",
COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '18:00:00' and '20:00:00' THEN 1 END) "1800-2000",
COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '20:00:00' and '22:00:00' THEN 1 END) "2000-2200",
COUNT(CASE WHEN right(left(wt.[started],19),8) between '22:00:00' and '23:59:59' THEN 1 END) "2200-2359"


from [workedtime] wt
inner join [staff] s on s.personid = wt.personid
group by concat(s.firstname, ' ',s.lastname), wt.[started], wt.finished
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas that could help?

Comment: Are the `Started` and `Finished` columns of type `datetime`? Your code makes it look like they're stored as strings, like `varchar(19)` or something.

Comment: Yes, in fact they are. This started as a mistake when doing the initial import SPs, but I'm loathed to convert them all now as it means rebuilding the DB. I suppose I could perform converts or casts at this level though?

Comment: Putting in the effort to have the appropriate datatypes now will save you *much more* hassle dealing with the strings further down the road.

Comment: @iamdave I promise I will, if you help me with this particular one lol

Comment: Where are you using this data?  Obviously you can't have a table with dynamic column headings as per your two examples.

Comment: It subsequently is loaded into Power BI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are loading this data into Power BI (or any reporting tool for that matter) you do not want to be orematurely pivoting your data into a bunch of columns, as that will make your reporting a lot harder.  Instead you want to keep your output nice and categorised, so the one column can be used as a grouping into tables and charts.

Something like the script below will do that for you, though I don't really think that you are approaching this whole situation in the best manner.

Ideally you would structure your Power BI data model using a Star Schema and include a Date and Time dimension that you can then use as category groups.  Your Fact data (hours worked) would then be loaded in with a row for each hour of their shift with associated metrics you need to report on.

---

#### SQL

```
declare @d table(PersonID varchar(10),Started datetime,Finished datetime,HoursWorked decimal(10,5));
insert into @d values
 ('Person1','2020-07-13T07:00:23','2020-07-13T14:30:23',7.30)
,('Person2','2020-07-13T22:00:12','2020-07-14T07:10:28',9.10);

declare @StartDate datetime = '2020-07-13',
        @EndDate   datetime = '2020-07-14';

select d.PersonID
      ,d.Started
      ,d.Finished
      ,cast(datepart(hour,t.s) as varchar(2)) + '-' + cast(datepart(hour,t.f) as varchar(2)) as HourPeriod
      ,datediff(minute,case when d.Started < t.s then t.s else d.Started end, case when d.Finished > t.f then t.f else d.Finished end) / 60. as HoursWorked
from @d as d
    cross apply(values(dateadd(hour,0,d.Started) ,dateadd(hour,2,d.Started))
                     ,(dateadd(hour,2,d.Started) ,dateadd(hour,4,d.Started))
                     ,(dateadd(hour,4,d.Started) ,dateadd(hour,6,d.Started))
                     ,(dateadd(hour,6,d.Started) ,dateadd(hour,8,d.Started))
                     ,(dateadd(hour,8,d.Started) ,dateadd(hour,10,d.Started))
                     ,(dateadd(hour,10,d.Started),dateadd(hour,12,d.Started))
                     ,(dateadd(hour,12,d.Started),dateadd(hour,14,d.Started))
                     ,(dateadd(hour,14,d.Started),dateadd(hour,16,d.Started))
                     ,(dateadd(hour,16,d.Started),dateadd(hour,18,d.Started))
                     ,(dateadd(hour,18,d.Started),dateadd(hour,10,d.Started))
                     ,(dateadd(hour,20,d.Started),dateadd(hour,22,d.Started))
                     ,(dateadd(hour,22,d.Started),dateadd(hour,24,d.Started))
               ) as t(s,f)
where d.Started <= t.f
    and d.Finished > t.s
order by d.PersonID
        ,t.s;
```

#### Output

```
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
| PersonID |         Started         |        Finished         | HourPeriod | HoursWorked |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
| Person1  | 2020-07-13 07:00:23.000 | 2020-07-13 14:30:23.000 | 7-9        |    2.000000 |
| Person1  | 2020-07-13 07:00:23.000 | 2020-07-13 14:30:23.000 | 9-11       |    2.000000 |
| Person1  | 2020-07-13 07:00:23.000 | 2020-07-13 14:30:23.000 | 11-13      |    2.000000 |
| Person1  | 2020-07-13 07:00:23.000 | 2020-07-13 14:30:23.000 | 13-15      |    1.500000 |
| Person2  | 2020-07-13 22:00:12.000 | 2020-07-14 07:10:28.000 | 22-0       |    2.000000 |
| Person2  | 2020-07-13 22:00:12.000 | 2020-07-14 07:10:28.000 | 0-2        |    2.000000 |
| Person2  | 2020-07-13 22:00:12.000 | 2020-07-14 07:10:28.000 | 2-4        |    2.000000 |
| Person2  | 2020-07-13 22:00:12.000 | 2020-07-14 07:10:28.000 | 4-6        |    2.000000 |
| Person2  | 2020-07-13 22:00:12.000 | 2020-07-14 07:10:28.000 | 6-8        |    1.166666 |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot and see how I go. I am sure I'm NOT going about it the right way, but this is only an internal tool I'm developing and not a commercial project. It will do for the purposes of what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries @Dan.  If this was the right answer to your question do please mark it as such for the benefit of others with a similar problem.

Comment: I will, thanks. The only issue - before I do that - I seem to have now is that it's saying "'t' has more columns than were specified in the column list". I'm not an idiot, but I can't seem to find where the issue is. Any ideas?

Comment: Incidentally, I don't know why I didn't think of cross apply, since I've used it elsewhere as part of this project...

Comment: Anyone else offer an idea?

Comment: @Dan did you amend the definition of the `values` table in `t` or not include both column names in the alias?  Your error is saying that you have specified more columns within the `values` than you have included in the `as t(s,f)` alias.  As you can see in my answer, there are two columns in the `values` (each test row of the script is a two column row) and two specified in the alias (`s` and `f`)

Comment: I think the issue was in the brackets I was using (to convert the string to datetime2). I recopied over your example, changed again the table identifier and put casts in the right places again, and it worked. I know this won't be laid out as it should be if I were a professional developer, but this does the job I need it to. Thank you so very much, I've marked this as the solution.

Comment: @Dan No worries, just be aware of just how not having the appropriate datatypes is already causing you problems

Answer (score 0):

just so i understand what you are trying to achieve: you show two example tables but then you say "run a query that totals the number of hours in that 24hr period"
Do just want to be able to run this query (and you produced these 2 tables because you think they will enable the query) or do you also need these tables because you need to know, for example, the time worked in each of these 2 hour slots?